# Windows phone calculate distance

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-agents, windows-mobile-gps

I am working on windows phone app.
public void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs e)
{}

Does this event work on every position change when application run in background not in foreground?
I want to calculate traveled distance at every 10 seconds while app run in background.How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Microsoft is very specific on what is allowed to run in the background.

[See this article for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202866%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)